# Most effective way for a windows forms application to communicate with a C# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am building a windows service application. The widows service will run as a domain service account.

I like to have GUI on top of the application so I can monitor the status of the work being done in the service application.

What would be the most effective way to have a WinForms (or wpf) application interact with my windows service code?

Ideally, in my WiForms application, I like to call a static method in my windows service application and send/get data.

I can see this is done by some of the windows management services and MMC such as IIS management UI.

A link to an online article or sample code would be a great help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at WCF, specifically, embedding a WCF service into your windows service, then you can hook up an endpoint that exposes it to whatever needs access to it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566691/WCF-From-a-Beginners-perspective-a-Tutorial

Comment: I know WCF. However, it would require more effort that I can afford to spend. Is there any easier way for a process call a static method or send a message into a windows service?

Comment: You can choose : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I would say wcf is the easiest, though I have seen many complicated setups, but it doesn't need to be, you can get away with a very simple binding and interface, I do have some sample code that I can hunt out for you.

Comment: have a look at this one: https://gorillacoding.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/using-wcf-for-inter-process-communication/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Custom Commands to poke your service in to doing something, but is not a 2 way process, you can only send commands to your service. 
So, less than ideal in most cases, but it is simple and you could use it to trigger your service to flush some state to the event log or a text file if you really don't want to mess with WCF...

https://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/